# Android image downloading and caching using Picasso

Tags: android, android-asynctask, picasso

In my project a background service downloads contents from remote database using asynctask. I would like to download all images from urls (saved in database) using Picasso in background service. These images will be used later in my app.

Is there any better solution to do this? or just use the one line code of Picasso in asynctask?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any better solution to do this? or just use the one line code
>   of Picasso in asynctask?

What do you mean by **better**? Is it about performance?

If you will have to download a lot of images, you might want to download them on the `service`. With this, your download will not stopped if the activity is destroyed.

For the library, i never use `Picasso`. I always use Universal Image Loader but i dont know which one is better. I think the most important feature of those libraries is their capability to cache the images.

UPDATE

For performance, you may want to combine the `Picasso/UIL` library with `PullToRefresh` library, especially when your `listview/gridview` want to load a lot of images.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was talking about performance. And I have to download a lot of images. Yes, I will use service to do this.

Comment: What you did is what i did, and its what people at my office did..so theres a great possibility what we did is right, or maybe we wrong together :) All i can suggest is about the service

Comment: @PromeNabid i just remember something, please see my edited answer :)